# I'm trying to rewrite/shorten the urls on my website using the web.xml file

Tags: java, url-rewriting, jetty, web.xml

For instance:

```
www.website.com/index.html
```

to

```
www.website.com/home
```

Is it possible to only edit the web.xml file and accomplish this?

If yes, what would I need to do?
If no, what else would I need to do?

I'm running Jetty.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Yes Jetty provides Rewrite Handler to do this. You can find the documentation on the [link](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Feature/Rewrite_Handler).

I request you to follow the documentation and if you still get the error you can give it here some specific error.